# reversible iterator

Tags: java, iterator

I am suppose to make a reversible iterator in java thats suppose to run through a binary tree in reverse and forward. ill but up the directions and what I've done so far.

> DIRECTIONS
>
> able find the next node (the inorder
>   successor) or the previous node (the
>   inorder predecessor) from the current
>   node. To find the next node, there are
>   two cases.
>
> The current node has a right child. In
>   this case, the next node is the
>   minimum node on the right side. Any
>   ancestor of the current node will
>   either have a smaller value or a
>   larger value than any node on the
>   right side (and the left side for that
>   matter).
>
> In this case, the next node can be
>   found as follows. First set node to
>   current.right, then while node.left is
>   not null, set node to node.left. After
>   the loop is finished, set next to
>   node.
>
> The current node does not have a right
>   child. In this case, the next node is
>   going to be an ancestor of the current
>   node. The current node might be a
>   right child of its parent, so the code
>   needs to keep going up the parent
>   field until it goes up a left link. It
>   is possible that the current node is
>   the maximum of the tree, so the next
>   node might be null.
>
> In this case, the next node can be
>   found as follows. First set child to
>   current and set parent to
>   current.parent. While parent is not
>   null and child == parent.right, set
>   child to parent and set parent to
>   parent.parent. After the while loop,
>   set next to parent.
>
> Finding the previous node is
>   symmetric. In the above descriptions,
>   switch left with right (and switch
>   "minimum" with "maximum").
>
> For the iterator() method, the first
>   call to the next method should return
>   the minimum element of the tree. For
>   the iterator(T start) method, the
>   first call to the next method should
>   return the smallest element that is
>   greater or equal to start.

```
// Returns an iterator over all the elements
public ReversibleIterator<T> iterator() {
    PublicBTNode<T> current = root;

    if(size==0)
        return null;
    if(current.right!=null){
        current.right=current;
        while(current.left!=null){
            current.left=current;
        }
    }
    return (ReversibleIterator<T>) new RIForLinkedList<T>(list);
}
// return an Iterator that starts with the first element
// that is greater than or equal to start
public ReversibleIterator<T> iterator(T start) {
    return null;

}
```

i think my iterator is wrong because i have some restrictions on this.:

Restrictions

The SortedBST class and any ReversibleIterator classes should not use arrays or ArrayLists. The iteration should be performed without creating new arrays, ArrayLists, or nodes.

but heres my iterator

```
enter code herepublic void iterator(PublicBTNode<T> node, ArrayList<T> list) {
    if (node == null)
        return;
    iterator(node.left, list);
    list.add(node.element);
    iterator(node.right, list);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: yeah i wanted to see if my coding was right to make a iterator go in reverse

Comment: Wouldn't a `ReversibleIterator` need a parameter to specify the desired direction?

Comment: Consider adding the `homework` tag?

Comment: yeah thats what the second iterator method is suppose to do i havent figred out how to do that one yet

Answer (score 2):

This code looks wrong:

```
if(current.right!=null){
    current.right=current;
    while(current.left!=null){
        current.left=current;
    }
}
```

I think is should be more like this:

```
    while(current.left!=null){
        current=current.left;
    }
```

The `current.right` part you don't need here.

But the important part is the implementation of your iterator, which we don't see.